# Tracing redirects with Headless Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

I'm using [CDP4J](https://github.com/webfolderio/cdp4j), though I expect this question relates directly to Google Chrome DevTools Protocol.

I want to get a list of the HTTP requests made for a webpage and response codes. So that would include the initial request in the main frame and subsequent requests, either made via 3xx redirects or JavaScript-originated navigation.

It's not clear how to do this reliably.

I have tried the following:

1. Store `io.webfolder.cdp.session.Session.getFrameId`
2. Add callback to session with `addEventListener`, record every event of type `io.webfolder.cdp.event.Event.NetworkResponseReceived`
3. Of these, filter those whose frame ID matches.
4. Of these filter on type `io.webfolder.cdp.type.page.ResourceType.Document`

I have a URL that I know returns a HTTP 303. But looking at the Events, don't see the original URL, but instead see only the final destination of the redirects. Every single NetworkResponseReceived has a status of 200.

How can I capture the chain of redirects?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. The `io.webfolder.cdp.event.network.RequestWillBeSent` event has `getRedirectResponse`, which contains a response if it's a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the ResponseReceived event for this purpose.  This seems to work to get the document URL from the event:

```
    if (session.getTargetId().equals(responseReceived.getFrameId()) && ResourceType.Document.equals(responseReceived.getType())) {
        String url = responseReceived.getResponse().getUrl();
        ...
    }
```